# how th the names of the quantified variables and the order in which they appear matters in the statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics

what are the difference between
"For all m there exists an n such that n = 2 × m"
and
"There exists an n such that for all m, n = 2 × m" in meaning?

Comment: Well, think about the rationals.  There the first statement is true...for every $m\in \mathbb Q$ there exists an $n\in \mathbb Q$ such that $n=2m$.  But the second statement is false.  There is no $n\in \mathbb Q$ such that for all $m\in \mathbb Q$ we have $n=2m$.

Comment: The issue is not with the name of the variables (that is immaterial: $\forall x (x \ge 0)$ has the same meaning of $\forall y ( y \ge 0)$ ) but with the order of the quantifiers.